# Select a binary matrix at random - Matlab

Tags: matlab, random, matrix, binary

I am working with largish binary matrices, at the moment up to 100x100.

Lets say I am working with 30x30 binary matrices. Then there are a total of 2^(30x30) binary matrices. I want to select a binary matrix at random, where each of the 2^(30x30) matrices has the same probability of being selected.

My solution attempt was to pick a number between 1 and 2^(30x30) using the function randi(n) with n = 2^(30x30) and then converting the result to the appropriate binary matrix. The problem I ran into was that randi(n) does not take values for n larger than 2^54. Matlab in general does not seem to like very large numbers.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If each matrix of booleans has equal probability, then the elements of the matrix each have equal probability of 0 and 1. You can just fill a matrix of the appropriate size with *n*² uniform random booleans.

I don't have MATLAB handy, but in Octave you'd do something like `unidrnd(2, n, n) - 1`.

Comment: Thanks, that seems so obvious now. A fresh perspective often helps... :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `randint` in the range [0 1]:

```
matrix=randint(30,30,[0 1]);
```

You can also use `rand` and threshold the resulting matrix:

```
matrix=rand(30,30);
matrix=round(matrix);
```

**EDIT**: just realized it also works with `randi` with the following syntax:

```
matrix=randi([0 1],30,30);
```

Comment: Thanks. I missed the connection that each individual element has equal probability of being either 1 or 0 as @larsmans pointed out.